# R language syntax highlight with react-ace

Tags: r, syntax, react-ace

Is it possible to highlight syntax error written in R on AceEditor (react-ace).

I am trying to use react ace editor to implement Online R IDE.

```
import AceEditor from "react-ace";
import 'brace/mode/r';
import 'brace/theme/kuroir';
import 'brace/ext/language_tools';

<AceEditor
 mode="r"
theme="cobalt"
onChange={this.onChange}
onSelectionChange={this.onSelectionChange}
name="ace-document-editor"
editorProps={{$blockScrolling: true}}
height={'100%'}
width={'100%'}
fontSize={14}
showPrintMargin={true}
showGutter={true}
highlightActiveLine={true}
value={rScript}
setOptions={{
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    enableSnippets: true,
    showLineNumbers: true,
    useWorker: true,
    tabSize: 2,
    }}
 ref="reactAceComponent"
 />
```

This code works fine, but it doesn't highlight incorrect syntax.